# Pytorch NLP model doesn’t use GPU when making inference

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, nvidia-jetson

I have a NLP model trained on Pytorch to be run in Jetson Xavier. I installed Jetson stats to monitor usage of CPU and GPU. When I run the Python script, only CPU cores work on-load, GPU bar does not increase. I have searched on Google about that with keywords of " How to check if pytorch is using the GPU?" and checked results on stackoverflow.com etc. According to their advices to someone else facing similar issue, cuda is available and there is cuda device in my Jetson Xavier. However, I don’t understand why GPU bar does not change, CPU core bars go to the ends.

I don’t want to use CPU, it takes so long to compute. In my opinion, it uses CPU, not GPU. How can I be sure and if it uses CPU, how can I change it to GPU?

**Note:** Model is taken from huggingface transformers library. I have tried to use cuda() method on the model. (model.cuda()) In this scenario, GPU is used but I can not get an output from model and raises exception.

Here is the code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, pipeline
import torch

BERT_DIR = "savasy/bert-base-turkish-squad"    

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(BERT_DIR)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(BERT_DIR)
nlp=pipeline("question-answering", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)


def infer(question,corpus):
    try:
        ans = nlp(question=question, context=corpus)
        return ans["answer"], ans["score"]
    except:
        ans = None
        pass

    return None, 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been solved with loading pipeline containing device parameter:

```
nlp = pipeline("question-answering", model=BERT_DIR, device=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the model to work on GPU, the data and the model has to be loaded to the GPU:

you can do this as follows:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, pipeline
import torch

BERT_DIR = "savasy/bert-base-turkish-squad"  
  
device = torch.device("cuda")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(BERT_DIR)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(BERT_DIR)
model.to(device) ## model to GPU

nlp=pipeline("question-answering", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)


def infer(question,corpus):
    try:
        ans = nlp(question=question.to(device), context=corpus.to(device)) ## data to GPU
        return ans["answer"], ans["score"]
    except:
        ans = None
        pass

    return None, 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However .to(device) method does not solve the problem. It raises a following exception: "Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for
>> argument #3 'index' in call to _th_index_select"

Comment: Thats because one of your data is still on CPU.